# Choosing parameters for HOUGH_GRADIENT_ALT

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, hough-transform, canny-operator

I am trying to solve this problems for hours already, and similar issues on StackOverflow did not help me.

Imagine I have this image (in reality it is a more complicated image but I'll stay with a simple example for now):

[image]

I do the following for the `HOUGH_GRADIENT`:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
img = cv2.cvtColor(cv2.imread("example.png"), cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
img_blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(img, (9, 9), 1.5)
edges = cv2.Canny(img_blur, threshold1=50, threshold2=250)
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(
    edges, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1.5, 20, 
    minRadius=10, maxRadius=100, param1=100, param2=100
)
img_cp = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
if circles is not None:
    circles = np.round(circles[0, :]).astype("int")
    for (x, y, r) in circles:
        cv2.circle(img_cp, (x, y), r, (0, 255, 0), 4)
```

This works without any problems and detects the inner circles just as I want:

[image]

I was trying to use `HOUGH_GRADIENT_ALT` instead as the OpenCV repo claims it to work better. From what I understand, most function call arguments should have the same meaning instead of `param1` and `param2`.

So, I try:

```
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(
edges, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT_ALT, 1.5, 20, 
minRadius=10, maxRadius=100, param1=300, param2=0.9
```

)

And I get nothing. I have tried many different parameters but to no result. Not only I do not understand how to fix it but also I do not understand why it would not work. Any help would be very appreciated.

OpenCV version 4.5.5.

Comment: Can you try to reduce param2 to 0.85 or even smaller? Also test cv.Scharr with param1 to make sure your circles are visible in the edge image.

Comment: disregard the answer given by supra an hour ago. he changed the method back to `HOUGH_GRADIENT`, which fundamentally doesn't address your question, which is about `HOUGH_GRADIENT_ALT`. but perhaps you can derive some ideas from the other API calls he uses to filter/smooth the image

Comment: HoughCircles does its own Canny. **do not** apply canny before passing the image to HoughCircles

Comment: @Micka.  I tried 0.85 and it worked on my code.

Answer (score 0):

I solved problem. Try this: Edit: we cannot used this `cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT_ALT`

```
#!/usr/bin/python39
#OpenCV 4.5.5 Raspberry Pi 3/B/4B-w/4/8GB RAM, Bullseye,v11.
#Date: 10th May, 2022

import numpy as np
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('circle.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
bilateral = cv2.bilateralFilter(gray,10,50,50)

minDist = 30
param1 = 30
param2 = 30
minRadius = 5
maxRadius = 100

circles = cv2.HoughCircles(bilateral, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, minDist, param1=param1, param2=param2, minRadius=minRadius, maxRadius=maxRadius)

if circles is not None:
    circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
    for i in circles[0,:]:
        cv2.circle(img, (i[0], i[1]), i[2], (0, 255, 0), 4)

cv2.imwrite('inner_circle.png', img)
# Show result for testing:
cv2.imshow('img', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Output:

[image]

Edit: we can `cv2.HOUGH_GRADINT_ALT` And used snipped from @Valeria.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2


img = cv2.imread('circle.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
bilateral = cv2.bilateralFilter(gray,10,50,50)       

#circles = cv2.HoughCircles(bilateral, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT_ALT, 1, minDist, param1=param1, param2=param2, minRadius=minRadius, maxRadius=maxRadius)
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(bilateral,
                           cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT_ALT,
                           1.5, 20,
                           minRadius=10, maxRadius=100,
                           param1=300, param2=0.9)

if circles is not None:
    circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
    for i in circles[0,:]:
        cv2.circle(img, (i[0], i[1]), i[2], (0, 255, 0), 4)

cv2.imwrite('inner_circle1.png', img)
# Show result for testing:
cv2.imshow('img', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Edit. Removed fix constant .

Answer (score 0):

HOUGH_GRADINT_ALT seems to be broken.
I have an image of a slightly deformed white circle with radius 230 on a black background that is about 420x420
I call this

HoughCircles(bordered, circles,HOUGH_GRADIENT_ALT
, 1 # dp. accumsize=imagesize and detect also 'small'
, 20 # mindist between circles
, 600# param1 = threshold for center,
, 0.7 # param2=[erfectness
, M, 362); # min,max

If I set M=194 it works. If I set M=193 or lower it does not work. From the documentation I understand this function should detect my circle even if I set it to 0.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).